# WordPress does not use my attachment.php template

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a really strange problem causing a WordPress site to display attachments/images with an old template. My attachment.php used to be a restyled version of twentytwelve's attachment template, but I revised it and put it up to production. But no matter what we do, the old template is used. Compare:

DEV: http://dev.metlifeyourlife.com/home-care/landscaping-to-keep-you-safe/attachment/father-and-daughter-8-9-years-preparing-to-plant-tree-in-front-of-house/

PROD: http://www.metlifeyourlife.com/home-care/landscaping-to-keep-you-safe/attachment/father-and-daughter-8-9-years-preparing-to-plant-tree-in-front-of-house/

IT insists the code on dev and prod are the same, and attachment.php does look correct in the wp-admin editor (Appearance > Editor). I started thinking about a caching issue but this has been like this for a few months.

The question is: what would cause this, and how can I get prod to match dev?

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Added, figured it was self-explanatory

Comment: Are you sure you are uploading the edited template? Are you sure it's being transferred to the server correctly. When you download the template after you've uploaded it, which version do you see?

Comment: I'm sure the edited template is up on dev, but I don't have prod access so I can't confirm what's there and can't download it. IT tells me attachment.php is identical on both. The best I can do is see the code in the WP admin, which does look right.

Comment: I just tried to implement a new solution and IT overwrote it with a file that shows the bad code (from Twenty_Eleven theme). Obviously the bad code still lives on prod somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

There's evidence that the old attachment file still exists on production somewhere, but I wanted to share my solution that ended up revealing this.

attachment.php is what WordPress usually uses for building attachment pages, but it will be overridden by a file titled based on MIME type. I renamed my attachment.php to image.php (since all our attachments are images) and this did get applied immediately.